# Add streams in Scala

Tags: scala, stream

I see at least two different implementations:

```
def add_streams(s1:Stream[Int], s2:Stream[Int]): Stream[Int] =
  Stream.cons(s1.head + s2.head, add_stream(s1.tail, s2.tail))
```

```
def add_streams(s1:Stream[Int], s2:Stream[Int]) =
  (s1 zip s2) map {case (x,y) => x + y}
```

I guess the last one is more efficient since it is not recursive.
Is it correct? How would you code such a function ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first version is broken as it doesn‘t check for the end of a `Stream`. (The streams needn’t be of different length for this to happen.) Given that, the `zip` version is the one to prefer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: your implementations have different behavior when either of the streams is finite. The first will crash with a `NoSuchElementException`, while the second will just truncate the longer stream.

I find the latter much more expressive and elegant, anyway, although I doubt the performance difference would be noticeable in most cases.